# How do I create a forever emitting event observable?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an observable that is of type bool and I need this observable to never stop emitting events, a forever emitting event observable. I know I could not call the dispose bag but that would create a memory leak so what would not be the best way to create this observable. I looked into using .interval but it seems like it only works on an observable type.

```
    viewModel.outputs.isAgentAvailable
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { [unowned self] isAgentAvailable in
            if isAgentAvailable {
                self.liveChatButton.isEnabled = true
                self.isAgentAvailableLabel.text = agentAvailableText
            } else {
                self.liveChatButton.isEnabled = false
                self.isAgentAvailableLabel.text = agentUnavailableText
                self.liveChatButton.alpha = 0.5
            }
        }
    ).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
extension Observable {
    public func never() -> Observable<Element> {
        return .merge(self, .never())
    }
}
```

*P.S.: But I don't understand why you need infinity observable?*

Comment: I just need to constantly update a button and this boolean will update that button hence why its has to emit infinite events.

Comment: but you can emit signal from your ViewModel, and updating your UI after your ViewModel emits signal. For example if you have some Api stuff, u can make some merge, and after answer emit signal to your output

Comment: but its not coming from any networking stuff, i'm using an sdk and after creating a chat object, its checking for the agent, sorry for being confusing.

Comment: u can create extension for your agent and observe states? did you try it?

Comment: no i didn't try that because i didn't even think of that, will do that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if `viewModel.outputs.isAgentAvailable` isn't emitting a completed or error event, then you already have what you want. Otherwise:

if it's cold, then use interval and concatMap (something like:)

```
Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(3), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .concatMap { _ in viewModel.outputs.isAgentAvailable }
```

If `isAgentAvailable` is hot, then remove the code that causes the completed event and it will stay alive.